# How do you access the top level of the DOM from jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe

Trying to figure this out... I'm trying to accessthe top level of the dom from inside an iframe. How possible is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From inside of a frame you can always get to the top level using `window.top`.  You can check to see if you are in a frame using:

```
var iAmInAFrame = (window.top == window.self);
```

You should be able to use `window.top.document.whatever` (e.g. body, getElementById(), etc.) to manipulate the top level document provided that you share a domain.

Answer (score 4):

You can append window.parent.document to your calls to get to the parent.

e.g.

```
$('body', window.parent.document).append("this is coming from my iframe");
```

**Edit:** As noted in the comments below the iframe must be served from the same domain as the parent or the browser's security restrictions will prevent this.

Comment: +1. Provided the iframe has access to the parent (same domain).

Answer (score 1):

To use selectors and jQuery functions in the inner DOM of an iframe, you can use the [Traversing/contents](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/contents) function.

```
$("iframe").contents().find("body").append("I'm in an iframe!");
```

Comment: I know that, but how do I access the outside world from inside the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

just use `document.firstElementChild`.
Worked for me. It gave the top level html element.